# Issue with KissXML pod with KFEpubKit

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I tried to install KFEpubKit with cocoapods.
The installation worked fine but when I tried to run my project, I got this error because of KissXML (which was auto included) :

```
Include of non-modular header inside framework module 'KissXML.DDXMLNode'
```

So I set the property

```
Allow Non-modular Includes in Frmaework Modules
```

to Yes
but I still have the error.
Any idea?

I know there are many similar issues but none of them solved mine.

Many thanks!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I actually chose not to use any library to read my ebook. So I unzip the epub file, parse the XML and read the book with a webview

Comment: Make sense, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.build_configuration_list.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
        configuration.build_settings['CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES'] = 'YES'
    end
end
```

at the end of your podfile would solve your problem. But then you would run into the next one... (That you can't build the Obj-C Module KFEpubKit)